# How to fix Hadoop3.1.2 "WARN util.NativeCodeLoader"

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop on my mac and tried to start it using start-dfs.sh. However, I kept getting the Warning message: WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable. Any suggestions on what files to modify?

```
Ms-MacBook-Pro% ./start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
localhost: datanode is running as process 48267.  Stop it first.
Starting secondary namenodes [Ms-MacBook-Pro.local]
Ms-MacBook-Pro.local: secondarynamenode is running as process 48390.  Stop it first.
2019-08-31 22:39:06,151 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Comment: ` datanode is running as process 48267.  Stop it first.`: It is already running, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks! It does show that the hadoop is running. However, when I go to http://localhost:50070 it shows "localhost refused to connect". Not sure what is the best way to correct that.

Comment: Did you try in root mode? `sudo su` => `start-dfs.sh`